# Solving the system $x^2-y^2=z , y^2-z^2=x , x+y+z=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many real solutions are there of the system of equations

$x^2-y^2=z , y^2-z^2=x , x+y+z=0$ ?

Comment: There are 4 solutions, which are all real integers. Try to include your approach to the problem or at least your mathematical background.

Answer (score 1):

We have the solutions $(x,y)=(0,0), (1,-1),(0,1), (-1,0)$. Substituting $z=-x-y$, the first two equations are $(x+y)(x-y+1)=0$ and $x(x+2y+1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\left(x-y+1\right)\left(x+y\right)=x^{2}-y^{2}+x+y=x^{2}-y^{2}-z=0$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$$ x^2-y^2=z , \,  y^2-z^2=x , \;  x+y+z=0$$
By adding (1) and (2)

$$x^2-z^2=x+z.$$
Therefore
$$x+z=0$$ or $$x-z=1.$$